# import custom component in app.js ReferenceError can't find variable: instructions

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and try to build some basic app. I'm trying to render a custom component named 'Home' in my app.js but i received the error: ReferenceEroor: Can't find variable:instructions . I tought this was one of the easiest things to add a custom component until this error.. Is anyone who could help me further?

Code app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Home from './src/Home';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
          <Home/>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }

});
```

Code Home.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';


const Home = () => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to Picoo!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
      )


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

Receiving this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tryind to access `instructions` variable declared in your Home componant file ... and it's declared in a different scope

```
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
```